# Is there generic way of checking if record is duplicated? It needs to be checked by Unique Constraint in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have Entities generated from Database. I upload data from Excel and Import them row by row to the Database. I have set Unique Constraint on a table so it doesn't allow duplicates. Before adding new record to DB I want to check if such already extists, not by ID but by properties that correspond with the Unique Constraint.

I can check this by doing Switch Case and typing every posibility. I want it to be generic but I don't know how. This is how I've done it so far:

(Object is an instance of class Entity and it has some properties filled with data)

```
var entityDuplicate = db.Entity.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == object.Name && f.Surname == object.Surname);
if(entityDuplicate == null)
{
    db.Entity.Add(object);
}
```

It works, but can I do this generic way? so I don't have to manually type everything? Like chceck unique constraint in SQL and check if table already has such record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a generic way you need to generate `f => f.Name == object.Name && f.Surname == object.Surname`

This can be done via Linq.Expression. You can start with defining your custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class MustBeUniqueAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Now in class you want to insert mark all properties that shoul be involved in comparasion with this attribute:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [MustBeUnique]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MustBeUnique]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can generate lambda expression:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreatExpression<T>(T toInsert)
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var membersToTrack = type.GetMembers(
        BindingFlags.GetField
        | BindingFlags.GetProperty
        | BindingFlags.Instance
        | BindingFlags.Public)
        .Where(m => m.CustomAttributes.Any(a => a.AttributeType == typeof(MustBeUniqueAttribute)))
        .ToArray();

    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    if (membersToTrack.Length == 0)
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Constant(false), parameter);

    Expression body = null;
    foreach (var member in membersToTrack)
    {
        object actualValue = null;
        if (member is PropertyInfo info)
            actualValue = info.GetValue(toInsert);
        else
            actualValue = ((FieldInfo) member).GetValue(toInsert);

        var leftExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, member.Name);
        var rightExpression= Expression.Constant(actualValue);
        var equalExpression = Expression.Equal(leftExpression, rightExpression);

        body = body == null ? equalExpression : Expression.AndAlso(body, equalExpression);
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    return lambda;
}
```

Usage:

```
var objectToInsert = // import from Excel
var expression = CreatExpression(objectToInsert);

var entityDuplicate = db.Entity.SingleOrDefault(expression);
if(entityDuplicate == null)
{
    db.Entity.Add(object);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can test it [online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vawehg)

Comment: Custom Attribute definition should be empty, right? It's just here to mark properties with new Attribute?

Comment: @Passer7by yes you are right. I'm using it just ot determine should this property be included in expression or not. This attribute allow you to change logic of expression generator without rewriting code: if you mark more properties with it, then they will be added to result expression

Comment: @Passer7by ofcourse you can make this attribute non-empty and pass some value to it. For example, you later may want that some strings compared in case-insensitive manner, but not all. In this case you may add a `bool toLowerCase` field to `MustBeUnique` attribute and read that value in expression generator.

Comment: Why did you used "I" in AttributeUsage? Isn't it more efficient to use "II"?

Comment: In Expression function the line "var tyoe = typeof(T);" returns me "Object" instead of "Entity" and then membersToTrack is always empty.

Comment: @Passer7by 1. _Why did you used "I"_ it is a [bitwise OR](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm). 2. _returns me "Object"_ actual type calcualtes from argument, so if you create your entity like `object entity = new Entity();` and pass it to `CreateExpression` it would be `Object`. You can fix it with `var type = toInsert.GetType();`

Comment: it solved the problem, but there is another: 'var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);' gives me an error: ParameterExpression of type Entity cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Object''. "parameter" is of type Entity but what is object in this line?

Comment: @Passer7by please show me how do you call `CreateExpression`. I've tested my code with Visual Studio and it works for me just as I expect. I did it something like `var objectToInsert = new Entity(); var lambda = CreateExpression(objectToInsert);` so in my case `T` is `Entity` and `typeof(T)` works fine. It looks like you calling it like `CreateExpression<Entity>(variableOfObjectType);` and that why you getting errors

Comment: I call it this way: "var expression = CreatExpression(instance);" instance is of type Entity and everything works except last line "var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);"

Comment: @Passer7by I've added a link to net fiddle, try it online. I'm pretty sure that while runtime type of `instance` is `Entity` it compile time type is `object`. For example if you call my expression builder in a `SaveMethod` method that looks like `void SaveEntity(object instance)`

Comment: I have list of Objects and then assigning to this lists instances using "(Object)Activator.CreateInstance(entityType)" and later it shows me this instance as "Entity" type. Before running your function I've created new Entity instance this way: "var toInsertCorrectType = Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);" and coppied values: "toInsertCorrectType = instance" and passed the "toInsertCorrectType" to function yet still the same error. Is this the problem? That it is object of type Entity?

Comment: @Passer7by your problem is in Activator. Method [CreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_) returns object, so when you call CreateExpression compiler does not know actual type of T.  Try do somethid like `var toInsert = Activator.CreateInstance<Entity>()` and then pass created object ot CreateExpression

Comment: I do that but toInsert still appears as Object.

Comment: when I cast this object to Entity type like so:"var toInsertCorrectType = (Entity)Activator.CreateInstance(entityType);" then it works, but I can do this way only doing switch case since I don't know which Entity will be passed. That's why I have this variable "entityType".

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a generic method to see if a record of an entity exists or not. You can use Any() method of DBSet class, and pass it the condition to search for the record.

```
public bool CheckIfEntityExistsByEntityId<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> expr)
{
    return _baseRepository.DbSet().Any(u => expr);
}
```

Comment: Is "_baseRepository"  deriving from DbContext? Because I've swapped it with my autogenerated class that contains my DbSets but it shows error that this class does not contain a definition for DbSet

Comment: _baseRepository in my case was the one which contained the connection. you can modify it as per your need. i would be needing too see more of your code to tell the exact thing, which wont be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the single record or on a set of records using Except Linq.
Create a dictionary of records from the database and a dictionary of records from the excel file.
This example instead of excel uses json, but the concept is the same.

```
`Dictionary<string, string> listProdOnDb = new Dictionary<string, string>();`
`Dictionary<string, string> listProdJson = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var item in ListaProdJson)
        {
            listProdJson.Add(item.codProdotto.Trim(), item.descrizione.Trim());
        }
strSql = "SELECT Cod_Prod_Rpt,Des_Prod_Rpt FROM xxxx Where xxxxx = xxx";
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql, connection))
            {
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                string[] col = { "", "" };
                while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                    if (!sdr.IsDBNull(0))
                        col[0] = sdr.GetString(0).Trim();

                    if (!sdr.IsDBNull(1))
                        col[1] = sdr.GetString(1).Trim();

                    // add items
                    if (col[0] != "") // check if key is valid
                        listProdOnDb.Add(col[0], col[1]);
                }

                }
            }

 IEnumerable<string> onlyInFirstSet = listProdJson.Keys.Except(listProdOnDb.Keys);
 if(onlyInFirstSet.Count() > 0) {
.....
 }
```

`